# calculating tpr and fpr

Tags: roc

While calculating the tpr and fpr, can I give both positive class probability or the actual predictions? it give different scores for me, please help me out

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to [`sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html).

As specified in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html):

> **y_score**
>
> ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
>
> Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).

So you need to give the probabilities.

This gives you the false positive rate and true positive rates for different thresholds.